# async job scheduling in nodejs using loop

Tags: node.js, asynchronous, cron

I have a JSON of tasks grouped in the interval (see `unit`) they are supposed to be repeated by `every` interval of `unit`.

```
 items=[
           { 
                "unit" : "minute",
                "detail" :
                 [ 
                    {"every" : 3, task : "task1"}
                    {"every" : 4, task : "task2"}...
                 ] 
           },
           { 
                "unit" : "day",
                "detail" :
                 [ 
                    {"every" : 3, task : "task3"}
                    {"every" : 4, task : "task4"}...
                 ] 
           },..
    ]
```

I used node-cron through following async function to schedule them on every `every` `unit` of intervals, like : task1 should happpen on every 3 minute.

I tried this code :

```
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
function cronify(callback) 
{
    for (var i in items)
    {
        for (var j in items[i].detail) {                        
            callback(items[i].unit,items[i].detail[j]);
        }
    }
}

cronify(function (duration, detail) {
    var when = '* * * * * *';
    switch(duration)
    {
        case 'minute' : 
            when = '* */'+detail.every+' * * * *';
            break;
        case 'hour' : 
            when = '* * */'+detail.every+' * * *';
            break;
        case 'day' :
            when = '* * * * */'+detail.every+' * *';
            break;
    }
    var job = new CronJob(when, function () {
        //Do the task for task
         }, null, true, "GMT");
    }        
});
```

But the problem is every task gets executed every second independent of the duration mentioned via `unit` and `every`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Yes, if you put asterisk(*) at second, than task will be executed every second of odd minutes in case of * */2 * * * *. To run task once in minute you can put 0 in seconds, than 0 */2 * * * *. Example code:

```
items = [{
    "unit": "minute",
    "detail": [{
        "every": 3,
        "task": "task1"
    }, {
        "every": 4,
        "task": "task2"
    }]
}, {
    "unit": "day",
    "detail": [{
        "every": 3,
        task: "task3"
    }, {
        "every": 4,
        task: "task4"
    }]
}];
var CronJob = require('cron').CronJob;
function cronify(callback) {
    for (var i in items) {
        for (var j in items[i].detail) {
            callback(items[i].unit, items[i].detail[j]);
        }
    }
}
cronify(function(duration, detail) {
    var when = '* * * * * *';
    switch (duration) {
        case 'minute':
            when = '0 */' + detail.every + ' * * * *';
            break;
        case 'hour':
            when = '0 0 */' + detail.every + ' * * *';
            break;
        case 'day':
            when = '0 0 0 0 */' + detail.every + ' *';
            break;
    }
    var job = new CronJob(when, function (when) {
            console.log(when);
         }, null, true, "GMT");
});
```